# Loop in dictionary in HTML

Tags: python, html, loops, dictionary

I have a Python script creating a dictionary and passing it to a html page to generate a report.

in Python:

```
data_query= {}
data_query["service1"] = "value1"
data_query["service2"] = "value2"
return data_query
```

in HTML:

```
% for name, count in data_query:
<tr>
<td>${name}</td>
<td>${count}</td>
</tr>
% endfor
```

it does not work, says that it does not return enough values.

I also tried (pointed out in a comment in the other question, that I deleted by mistake):

```
% for name, count in dict.iteritems():
```

It does not give any error, but does not work. Displays nothing.

```
${len(dict)}
```

gives the right dictionary length

```
${len(dict.iteritems())}
```

does not display anything and seem to have a weird effect on my table format.

Is there a way to iterate correctly a dictionart in HTMl to display both the key and value?

EDIT: How I transfer the dictionary to the html page.

```
from mako.lookup import TemplateLookup
from mako.runtime import Context
from mako.exceptions import text_error_template

html_lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=[os.path.join(self.dir_name)])
html_template = html_lookup.get_template('/templates/report.html')
html_data = { 'data_queries' : data_queries }
html_ctx = Context(html_file, **html_data)
try:
    html_template.render_context(html_ctx)
except:
    print text_error_template().render(full=False)
    html_file.close()
    return
html_file.close()
```

Comment: First of all, I would recommend you to use a different variable name instead of `dict`

Comment: Sorry, `dict` was for the purpose of the code here, to make it clear that this was the dictionary. The real name is `data_query`.

Comment: How are the Python code and HTML communicating? Is there some kind of framework involved?

Comment: What templating language are you using? Also, how is the data being sent from the backend >?

Comment: I feel pretty stupid now... iteritems() was working, I just make a mistake in my formatting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
% for name, count in dict.items:
<tr>
<td>${name}</td>
<td>${count}</td>
</tr>
% endfor
```

should probably work ... typically you dont call the fn when you pass it to a templating language... alternatively

```
% for name in dict:
<tr>
<td>${name}</td>
<td>${dict[name]}</td>
</tr>
% endfor
```

would likely also work

as an aside ... dict is a terrible variable name as it shadows the builtin dict (which might be part of your problem if that is actually your variable name)

Comment: I made a mistake in the data I was transmitting to the template, so .iteritems() was working. However, .items works too.

Comment: When tested it simply prints out  % for name in dict: with the information and % endfor, but not as a table? its not recognizing the loop.

Comment: Also $ dont work prints ${name} etc. Is it perhaps a version issues?